# schema.post('find') and schema.post('findOne')

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

**app.js**

```
Match.find({}).lean().exec(function(err, matches) {});
Match.findById(id).lean().exec(function(err, match) {});
```

I use both of these queries in different routes.

**Match-Model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var messageSchema = new Schema({
    // ...
    message: {type: String, required: true},
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

var matchSchema = new Schema({
    // ...
    messages: [messageSchema]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

matchSchema.post('find', function(result) {
    result.forEach(function(chat) {
        chat.messages.forEach(function(message) {
            message.createdAt = new Date(message.createdAt).getTime();
            message.updatedAt = new Date(message.updatedAt).getTime();
        });
    });
});

matchSchema.post('findOne', function(result) {
    if (result !== null) {
        result.messages.forEach(function(message) {
            message.createdAt = new Date(message.createdAt).getTime();
            message.updatedAt = new Date(message.updatedAt).getTime();
        });
    }
});

var Match = mongoose.model('Match', matchSchema);

module.exports = Match;
```

Parsing the default date format (like `2016-05-19T13:29:07.731Z`) in Java (which I use on client side) is a pain, that's why I instead overwrite it with the unix timestamp, which is easy to format in Java.
The problem with this is, I have duplicate code (`message.createdAt` = ... and `message.updatedAt` ..) for `find` and `findOne`.
Is there a hook which triggers for both queries `find` and `findByID`? So I only have to write my code once? Because `find` won't trigger for `findById`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both hooks already look very similar, you could combine them into one function that gets used by all (similar) hooks:

```
function processResult(result) {
  if (result) {
    if (! Array.isArray(result)) {
      result = [ result ];
    }
    result.forEach(function(chat) {
        chat.messages.forEach(function(message) {
            message.createdAt = new Date(message.createdAt).getTime();
            message.updatedAt = new Date(message.updatedAt).getTime();
        });
    });
  }
}

matchSchema.post('find',    processResult);
matchSchema.post('findOne', processResult);
```

I believe that `findOne` will trigger for `findById`, so that should be covered as well.

Comment: Yes, that will do it. But anyways, is there no **hook** for all different select (find/findOne/findById) types?

Comment: No, there doesn't seem to be a single hook that will catch all of those.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still searching for this, there is a hook that will be called after each database access function.

```
schema.post('init', function(doc) {
  console.log('%s has been initialized from the db', doc._id);
});
```

The only problem with this hooks is that is syncronous and cannot handle promises.

Documented here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#synchronous